# Garbage Collector в неуправляемом коде

Tags: java, c#, .net, сборщик-мусора

Если я создам массив байт, например, и передам указатель на него в неуправляемый код, что с этим массивом будет делать Garbage Collector?

Comment: что значит неуправляемый код?

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov, машинный, нативный, который выполняется не под CLR

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В C# это зависит от того, как вы передаёте массив в неуправляемый код.

Обычно сборщик мусора имеет право в любой момент переместить любой управляемый объект в памяти. Чтобы этого не произошло, вы должны *прикрепить* объект, чтобы сборщик мусора не пытался его переместить. Для этого существует несколько методов, например, [ключевое слово `fixed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx):

```
unsafe void F()
{
    int[] data = { 1, 2, 3 };
    fixed (int* p = &data[0])
    {
        // тут у вас есть указатель, можно передавать его в нативный код
    }
}
```

Понятно, данные будут закреплены **лишь в области действия `fixed`**, поэтому если вы запомните указатель в переменной и воспользуетесь им по окончанию блока `fixed`, ваша память может быть перемещена или собрана сборщиком мусора, и вы на пути к undefined behaviour, как в старые недобрые времена. Ответственность за корректность поведения `unsafe`-кода лежит на вас и только на вас.

Для ручной работы с адресами вам могут понадобиться `IntPtr` (для представления указателя в безопасном коде), [`GCHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle(v=vs.110).aspx) (для низкоуровневого обращения с объектами с точки зрения сборщика мусора) и особенно [`Marshal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal(v=vs.110).aspx) для ручного преобразования между нативными и управляемыми объектами.

---

Другой метод передавать нативной функции массив — вызов через P/Invoke. В этом случае то же самое делает за вас маршаллер. Вам придётся выписать правильную сигнатуру P/Invoke, наподобие такой:

```
void F(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=1)]
    long[] ar,
    int size);
```

(сигнатуры можно составить самому, вдумчиво почитав [документацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eaw10et3(v=vs.110).aspx), или подсмотреть сигнатуры для популярных функций WinAPI на http://pinvoke.net). Маршаллинг не может проверить правильность сигнатуры, поэтому если вы ошибётесь, последствия, думаю, понятны.

Answer (score 2):

В Java сборщик мусора не удалит массив, пока на него есть ссылка, но может его переместить. Поэтому, перед тем как работать с массивом, требуется в неуправляемом коде вызвать метод `GetByteArrayElements` или `GetPrimitiveArrayCritical`. Спецификация не накладывает жёстких требований к реализации этих методов и оставляет их на усмотрение реализации виртуальной машины. Скорее всего, `GetByteArrayElements` создаст копию в *direct memory*, а `GetPrimitiveArrayCritical` закрепит массив в куче. Во втором случае лучше не удерживать ссылку долго и не делать вызовов к виртуальной машине до освобождения ссылки. Естественно, в обоих случаях массив надо освободить до выхода из нативного метода.